# Android - cannot re-enable keyguard while screen is off

Tags: android, keyguard

I'm trying to get my app to reenable the keyguard after x amount of time passes (using alarm manager).
Basically, here is what I do:

Let's say I set the screen lock to be enabled after 5 minutes.

1. My app starts and I disable the keyguard - works great!
2. I create a timer(using alarm manager) to lock the screen after 3 minutes and I see in the logs that the alarm goes off in 3 minutes and the code for re-enabling the keyguard kicks off. Screen goes off after 5 minutes and I click the power button and keyguard is enabled - works great!
   Basically, everything works fine as long as everything is done while the screen is on.

Now let's say we keep the same scenario as above, but change step 2 to:

1. Same as above
2. I create a timer(using alarm manager) to lock the screen after 10 minutes. Screen goes off after 5 minutes and I still see in the logs that the alarm goes off correctly after 10 minutes and re-enables the keyguard. However, when I click the power button after that, I can still enter the app without encountering the lock screen. If I either click the power button or wait for the screen to go off again, then I will encounter the lock screen.

This seems to indicate to me that re-enabling the keyguard only takes affect after the screen goes on again and you cannot enable it while the screen is off. Am I wrong or is there another way around this?
I would like to be able to kick the user back to the lock screen even if the code re-enables the lock guard while the screen is off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to use:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, this.getClass().getSimpleName());
wl.acquire();
```

before re-enabling the keyguard

Comment: Nice one - this looks like a solution to a similar problem I have. Did you release the wakelock after re-enabling the keyguard?